# Match multiple consonant-vowel sequences

Tags: javascript, regex

This `RegExp` gets me a consonant followed by a vowel, CV. I want to repeat this a variable number of times so I get something like CVCVCV without having a super long regular expression.

```
var regEx1 = new RegExp(/\b[b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]/);
```

How do I write this so that `[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]` and `[aeiou]` are variables and inserted in the `new RegExp`?

I tried this but it's not working:

```
  var consonant = "[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]";
  var vowel = "[aeiou]";
  var regEx1 = new RegExp(/\b + consonant + vowel +/);
```

Comment: You can't use variables inside regex literal notation. You would need to do some string manipulation and then pass it as a parameter to `RegExp`. (Btw, you don't need to use the `RegExp` constructor if you're using regex literal notation with `/.../`)

Comment: It also looks like you just need a quantifier in your regex, if you want to repeat those 2 character classes.

Comment: You say you want to "repeat a consonant followed by a vowel a variable number of times", but the example CVCVC does not follow that pattern--it's a consonant followed by a vowel two times, then followed by an extra consonant. Do you really want to match CVCVC, or was that a typo for CVCVCV? By the way, by a "variable number of times" do you mean a fixed number of times, or an arbitrary number of times?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using grouping and quantifiers you can achieve this.

(x) Matches x and remembers the match.

x{n} Where n is a positive integer. Matches exactly n occurrences of the preceding item x.

To match 3 times: CVCVCV

```
var regEx1 = /\b([b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]){3}/;
```

To match 12 times: CVCVCVCVCVCVCVCVCVCVCVCV

```
var regEx1 = /\b([b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou]){12}/;
```

For 0 or more times: (CVCVCVCV ...)

```
var regEx1 = /\b([b-df-hj-np-tv-z][aeiou])*/;
```

More info:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

UPDATE:

Based on your comment, is this what you are looking for?

```
var count = 3;
var consonant = '[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]';
var vowel = '[aeiou]';
var regEx1 = new RegEx('\\b(' + consonant + vowel + '){' + count + '}');
```

Comment: You might want to note that the `n` isn't actually a variable. You have to put an actual number there.

Comment: @4castle so `n` can't be a variable equal to 5?

Comment: I understand I can use quantifiers, thank you. My question is how can that quantifier be a variable.

Comment: @MichaelRader I updated, is this what you are asking?